# Is there a word for the opposite of magnify?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Specifically to do with lenses / magnification, but making something appear smaller rather than larger.

Example:

If her glasses make her eyes look larger:

> Her glasses magnify her eyes.

If her glasses make her eyes look smaller:

> Her glasses ______ her eyes. (opposite of magnify)

Comment: Questions entirely answerable by a thesaurus are off-topic. If you have checked one and it doesn't answer your question, please [edit] to explain why the words you found don't work.

Comment: My question is not answerable by a thesaurus (as far as I can tell). I stated in my question that I am looking for a word related to the use of lenses. All thesauruses I have checked to not have an antonym to magnify that relates to the use of lenses. 
@Laurel Do you want me to list every antonym to magnify and explain that it does not relate to using lenses?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do. That way, it prevents answerers from spending time giving you answers you've already discarded. Also please be sure to give a sentence where you would use the word (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for more info).

Comment: It does not seem reasonable to require the question asker to list all of the antonyms that do not fit the question, especially when the question explicitly states that the request is for a word related to the use of lenses. Is my question not clear that I am looking for a word related to the use of lenses?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with *shrink* or many of its [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/shrink). You keep saying that you want something specific to lenses. But *magnify* itself is not specific to lenses—so how can we interpret the opposite?

Comment: @tehp You don't have to list all the antonyms you find. But simply saying something like "I checked a thesaurus, and the words I found weren't suitable for my needs" goes a long way in people's attitude toward the question. Many people come here with no prior research, and users are wary of that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **reduce**.

> You can *magnify* the size of an image
>
> You can **reduce** the size of an image

By definition:

> make smaller or less in amount, degree, or **size**

If you are looking something related to lenses use **demagnify**.

> to reduce the size of (something, such as a photographic image or an electron beam)

You could say:

> I am going to demagnify this

Or:

> I am an expert in demagnification

Comment: Reduce is good, but I am looking specifically for something related to the use of lenses.

Comment: @tehp edited post. Use demagnification

Comment: @DManokhin I suppose the point the OP is struggling with is exemplified by the first part of your answer. You have said "magnify the size of the image". One could simply have said "magnify the image". The words "size of" are superfluous. Unfortunately it doesn't work quite like that for "reduce".

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this word used as the opposite of *magnify*, but it's been in specialist fields. That word is *minify*. However, dictionaries list this word. It seems to have come about analogously using *magnify* as a model:

> 2.(with object)  
> To reduce in actual size or amount; (now) especially to reduce the size of (an image).
>  From classical Latin
>   min- + -ify, after magnify.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/minify)
>
> To make smaller or less significant; reduce.
>  [min(imum) +
>   (magn)ify.]
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/minify)
>
> (tr)
>   rare
>  to minimize or lessen the size or importance of
>   (something)
>  from Latin minus less; for form, compare magnify
>   [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/minify)
>
> 1.to make less.
>   2.to minimize.
>  Latin min(us ) less + -ify, modeled on magnify 
>  [Random House Unabridged Dictionary (dictionary.com)](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/minify)
>
> lessen
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minifying)
>
> 2.To reduce in apparent size, as for example objects viewed through a lens or mirror shaped so as to increase the field of view, such as a
>   convex or aspheric mirror or a Fresnel lens.
>  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minify)
>
> minification
>  redirected from *minify*
>  A reduction in the
>   apparent size of an object. Example: viewing a distant object through
>   the objective of a galilean telescope. Syn. negative
>   magnification.
>  [Dictionary of Optometry and Visual Science](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/minification)
>
> Minification
>  Magnification, by a factor of less than one,
>   producing a smaller image.
>  [Wikipedia magnification disambiguation
>   page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification)

**Quotes:**

> Contact lenses neither magnify nor minify the image because they are
>   placed on your cornea.
>  [Physics of the Human Body, 2007](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=vtubxNaSAdAC&pg=PA686&dq=minify&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG8oe5zPvfAhVCXisKHaV4DUE4KBDoAQgpMAA#v=onepage&q=minify&f=false)
>
> The most common types are reverse telescopes ... which minify objects
>   being viewed but present more information by means of the enlarged
>   visual field.
>  [Dictionary of Optometry and Visual Science, 2014](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=3gygBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&dq=minify&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG8oe5zPvfAhVCXisKHaV4DUE4KBDoAQg2MAI#v=onepage&q=minify&f=false)
>
> Figure 3.13b is a photograph taken through a 35-mm lens which minified the optic array by a factor of .70 ...
>  
>   [The Perception of Pictures: Alberti's window, the projective model of pictorial information, 1980.](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=GJ8oAAAAYAAJ&q=minified&dq=minified&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz0uLw4fvfAhWIfysKHfv8BoA4FBDoAQhXMAk)
>
> Some lenses magnify, others make things smaller (minify). How much they magnify or minify can be calculated, but we have to know the actual numbers in your prescription(s)...
>   [From a reddit forum post on optometry board](https://www.reddit.com/r/optometry/comments/25z9oq/my_new_glasses_magnify_the_world_too_much_help/)
>
> The lenses in your glasses can magnify or minify the look of your eyes. WHY?!
>  
>   [Facebook post from Adra Eye Care](https://www.facebook.com/adraeyecarecenter/posts/why-do-my-glasses-make-my-eyes-look-bigger-or-smaller-depending-on-your-prescrip/314332195338969/)

It also comes up in thesauruses. However as you can see, it seems to be a term that's arisen after magnification to mean its opposite, and is probably not often used outside of specialist domains. In light of that, and since you don't seem to writing a technical or academic piece, you may want to use a more common English word.